# Azure: Web Apps - List Application Settings from deployed nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-identity

I've deployed a nodeJs app to a Linux Azure AppService. Now I would like to [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings) the server settings of that same app-service. Under the `Identity` tab I enabled the managed Identity for this AppService. In my NodeJs App I've tried the following:

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

credential.getToken().then(token => {
  ...
});
```

I'm not really sure what this is doing, but I don't think it connects, because the `getToken` never resolves. Any suggestions what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get server setting values inside of the app service, you can just try `process.env.NODE_ENV` as [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#access-environment-variables) indicated. Instead of calling Azure management API.

If you want to get server setting values outside of the app service, your code can't access server setting values directly, so you should call Azure management API. If you have some problem with `DefaultAzureCredential`, you can try `ClientSecretCredential`. Just try the code below:

```
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

const fetch = require("node-fetch")

let  tenantId='';
let  clientID = '';
let clientSecret = '';

let subscriptionID = ''
let resourceGroup = ''
let appServiceName = ''

new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId,clientID,clientSecret).getToken(['https://management.azure.com/.default']).then(result=>{
    accessToken = result.token
    reqURL = `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/${appServiceName}/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2019-08-01`
    fetch(reqURL, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  accessToken},
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));

})
```

Result :

[image]
[image]

For how to create an Azure AD app and assign a role to it so that it could have permission to call Azure mgmt APIs, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

Comment: My goal is to read and write settings. So, I agree, for reading you can use environment variables. But what about changing them, is all that AD app necessary?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri, yes, I think you should call Azure management API if you need to write/modify environment variables.

Comment: ok. but where can I find the **clientID** and **clientSecret** which you are using in your example?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri, you need to register an Azure AD app:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal so that you can get the clientID and create an secret :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri after you finished this 2 steps, you need to assign subscription role to this app so that this app will have permission to query resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application

Comment: I have your code working, thanks! Is there also a sdk or lib for this that I can use, like ms-rest.js or something like this that you know of?

Comment: For Azure management API, yes, see this : https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-resource/